# Can't find [formGroup] in angular 6 Unit Test

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-test

Let's say, I have maintained TDD to develop a new feature. I have a test scenario to make sure form has `[formGroup]` attribute with value `loginForm` like

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm"></form>
```

**login.componenet.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
            email: [''],
            password: ['']
        });
    }
}
```

**login.componenet.spec.ts**

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
    let component: LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                LoginComponent
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it(`show have as formGroup 'loginForm'`, () => {
        const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        console.log(compiled.querySelector('form'));
    })
});
```

Here, I got log at the console like [image]

So, how can I complete the test OR am I in wrong direction to test the scenario?

Comment: I have already looked into different site but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css selector to grab your form and check for it's attribute:

Something like:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myFormElement')).attributes['formGroup'];
```